# service-worker Is there a way to get informed if client quit?

Tags: service-worker

I have following setup.

SERVER (localhost/index.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
            // Register service worker
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(reg){
                    console.log("SW registration succeeded. Scope is "+reg.scope);
                }).catch(function(err){
                console.error("SW registration failed with error "+err);
                });
        }
    </script>
```

CLIENTS (e.g. localhost/client1.html)

```
<script>
    function send_message_to_sw(msg){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            // Create a Message Channel
            var msg_chan = new MessageChannel();

            // Handler for recieving message reply from service worker
            msg_chan.port1.onmessage = function(event){
                if(event.data.error){
                    reject(event.data.error);
                }else{
                    resolve(event.data);
                }
            };

            // Send message to service worker along with port for reply
            navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage("Client 2 says '"+msg+"'", [msg_chan.port2]);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way to get informed in service-worker when a client closed his window?

Answer (score 1):

Adding event listeners for either the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) or [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) events is the standard way of scheduling code to run before a tab/window is closed. Asynchronous code isn't guaranteed to execute before the window is destroyed, but it's your best bet.

You don't explain *why* you need to let the service worker know about a client window closing, though. You should take some time to think about whether it's actually needed for your use case. If you need to keep track of which client is associated with which requests, you can make use of the [`FetchEvent.clientId`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#fetch-event-clientid) property inside a `fetch` event handler. If you need to obtain the complete list of clients, you can do so within a service worker via [`clients.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/matchAll).

Comment: Service worker should still be able to notify us when a client is controlled or closed.